# Run Hive queries on local mode with Hadoop YARN

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, bigdata

Most examples run Hive in local mode mention using the following command.

```
SET mapred.job.tracker=local
```

But with YARN, how we execute Hive Job on Local mode, when running on YARN Cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with Yarn (I tested it with beeline):
set mapreduce.framework.name=local;